# Need example on building restful wcf web service with vb.net syntax

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

What I need is a good example of creating restful wcf with vb.net syntax, but all I can find is C# examples, and I spend my time trying to convert to vb.net. If anyone knows of good sample code in vb.net please let me know, or send me a link.

I would like to see how to create and consume collection data.  anything would be a big help, I am struggling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried having a look at this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178(v=vs.90).aspx

or this:

http://www.vb-tips.com/Making_a_REST_service_with_VB_and_WCF.aspx

I know that there's somewhat limited resources in VB.NET out there, but look at the c# ones and get the idea of how yo achieve it and then implement the same thing in VB.NET, I promise it's not that hard, I've gone from VB.NET to C# myself once.

Comment: thanks for the response, if anyone has some sample code please let me know.